# What's the rule on pastebin use?

Tags: discussion, questions

If someone pastes something on pastebin or pastie or some similar site and links the result in their question, should I pull that data in?

I've seen people do that for images, so I adapted that practise. I kinda got the feeling that it is preferred to keep all relevant information on this site (especially since other sites may go down, taking the information with them).
Is this even true? If it is, should I continue doing it for generic pieces of output?

I just did that [here](https://superuser.com/questions/388115/interpreting-output-of-cat-proc-cpuinfo) if someone want's to know what I'm talking about.

Comment: What do you mean "generic pieces of output"?

Comment: Like output from the shell or log files. I have a hard time finding a proper term for what I have in mind, but the question I linked is a good example of what I was thinking about.

Comment: Additionally, if you have so much content that putting it in the post is unpractical, chances are you didn't reduce it enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think we should be, it's just like link rot for tutorials. Simply copy the raw content in, and highlight it, pressing the code button on markdown. This will ensure it isn't lost from some pastebin content being deleted after X amount of time.

**Tl:dr: Yes, bring the code itself into your post.**